# Can't connect to local MySQL server, Lost connection, Server has gone away

Tags: mysql, centos

I have a very strange problem with my server.

First, the server crashed.
I use CPanel and WHM. And as I was not able to access I used SSH to restart the server. And it worked, back to normal.

But soon after began to be a new problem:
"Can not connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)"
"MySQL server has gone away"
"Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104"
"Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 104"

But these errors are not always, so that the site is online and working, just having this problem at one time or another, or in CPanel and mysqltuner this error is also shown.

The first thing I did: search.

I changed the my.cnf (added the socks), not resolved.
I rebooted the server, not solved.
I came back with an old my.cnf (which had backup), not resolved.
I tried changing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' but created a new problem "can not connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'."

I tried everything I could find.
Nothing solved.

Furthermore, the process of "mysqld" is always restarting!
Before, the process spent hours / days / weeks without restarting. At the "top" command was shown that mysqld was over 50 hours, 100 hours in "time +". but now, no more than 10 minutes. In other words, the process is restarting!

In "-m free", I have server 1303 free, and the "top" using processor is 4.5% "CPU (s)".

And another mysterious thing, is that "cron jobs" that are not working.
I have a cron job to TRUNCATE and INSERT data. The TRUNCATE works, the INSERT / SELECT not.

Need some help in order to fix the problem. '(

I have only this server, with Centos system.

## Edit:

```
140910 12:32:01  InnoDB: error: space object of table 'w_w/SRands',
InnoDB: space id 274796 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
InnoDB: Error: tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 0 0.
InnoDB: Was only able to read 0.
140910 12:32:01  InnoDB: Operating system error number 0 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 0 means 'Success'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File operation call: 'read'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
140910 12:32:01 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
140910 12:32:01 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
140910 12:32:02 [Warning] Using unique option prefix join_buffer instead of join_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140910 12:32:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140910 12:32:02 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140910 12:32:02 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140910 12:32:02 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140910 12:32:02 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140910 12:32:02 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 119.0M
140910 12:32:02 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140910 12:32:02 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 395690234452
140910 12:32:02  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Error: the size of single-table tablespace file ./w_w/SRands.ibd
InnoDB: is only 0 0, should be at least 65536!InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 395690846835
140910 12:32:02  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 5$
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
140910 12:32:03  InnoDB: Error: table 'w_w/SRands'
InnoDB: in InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 274796,
InnoDB: but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have
InnoDB: you deleted or moved .ibd files?
InnoDB: This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
InnoDB: whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the
InnoDB: table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
140910 12:32:03  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140910 12:32:04 InnoDB: 5.5.37 started; log sequence number 395690846835
140910 12:32:04 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
140910 12:32:04 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
140910 12:32:04 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
140910 12:32:04 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 1 event
140910 12:32:04 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.37-cll'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: You're already answering part of your question yourself. The server is continuesly restarting. So it's quite obvious that from time to time (during those restarts) it can't connect to the MySQL server. You'll have to figure out why it's restarting. Maybe there's a cronjob causing this?

Comment: The cronjob is old, and has always worked, and it is every 1 minute (to Truncate and Insert, like a tmp table): Truncate works, the Insert not. MySQL crashes every 10 ~ 16 minutes for "no reason". In the logs there is no error. :\

Comment: What does the mysql log look like at the time of a crash? can you paste from several lines before up to maybe one or two after the crash?

Comment: Paste the last couple of lines from the logs. Even if there's no error. There might be some usefull information in it.

Comment: I update, i found errors on LOG. I have two website in same server.  And, i think one table is corrupt. I can drop it? But, without delete data of two website?